# How to express "From the point of view of Information Theory"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I would like start a sentence with "From the point of view of information theory, ...", but this sounds a bit uneloquent to me. Can I say, "From an information theoretical point of view, ...", or would that be wrong, too? What would be a good way to say this?

Comment: How about "..... from the point of view of Information Theory" instead? e.g. start with what is importent

Comment: @mplungjan though it can work just as well the opposite way around, especially with longer sentences; get the necessary qualifications out of the way and then concentrate on the important part.

Comment: An information theoretic model (of the system) reveals pungent dysphonia between...

Comment: From an information-theoretical standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the near-synonym *perspective*:

> From the point of view of information theory...
>
> From an information theoretical point of view...
>
> From an information theory point of view...
>
> ...from the point of view of information theory.
>
> ...from an information theoretical point of view.
>
> ...from an information theory point of view.
>
> From the perspective of information theory...
>
> From an information theoretical perspective...
>
> From an information theory perspective...
>
> ...from the perspective of information theory.
>
> ...from an information theoretical perspective.
>
> ...from an information theory perspective.

Are all valid. *Perspective* has the minor advantage that "point of view" can mean both a way of looking at something, and also an individual opinion, which a field clearly can't have. (A minor advantage only, because it's the sort of semi-ambiguity that can't cause any real confusion, just perhaps break some readers' flow).

I would though say that "information theoretical" reads a bit strangely to me, but that's out of context, and opining strongly on which is or isn't inelegant is pointless without the full sentence, because how each of these flows (or doesn't) with the rest will affect its euphony.

Comment: _Information theory_ and _euphony_. Sounds like a remake of Snow White :-)

Comment: 'From an information **theory** point of view,' not 'From an information theoretical point of view'. As are all other instances of *theoretical*.

Comment: @Kris Care to explain why?

Comment: @Kris: would you say *from a **historical** point of view* or *from a **history** point of view*?

Comment: @PeterShor Though while I'd prefer "historical point of view", I certainly would prefer "information theory point of view" or for that matter "late mediaeval history point of view". Still, *prefer* is different to "not".

Comment: @PeterShor And up voter: You are obviously in a tearing hurry lol. I'd certainly not say *historical*, if I meant *history*. The current context has nothing to do with *theoretical* and everything to do with *theory*. I'm sure you will agree with a little application of thought. See also JonHanna: "late medieval history point of view", not "late medieval historical point of view".

Comment: @Kris how can something have "nothing to do with theoretical and everything to do with theory" when they're adjective and noun forms of the same thing. They're modifying a noun, so they can do so as an adjective or as a noun serving as an adjective.

Comment: Curious as to why you switch between "the" and "an" depending on the word order. Both apply to "perspective", so shouldn't the same article be used in all cases? (That might sound strange, but logic demands consistency)

Answer (score 0):

> "Information theory tells us that ..."

might be a simpler and more idiomatic way of putting it.